# Combinatorics question about addition

Tags: combinatorics, inequality

I noticed the following happening and I wonder if it can be proved:

Assume $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ are positive integers and $h$ is their least common multiple.  Now assume
$$a_1x_1 + \cdots a_nx_n > h$$
where the $a_i$ are non-negative.  I'd like to show that there always exist $0 \leq b_i \leq a_i$ such that
$$b_1x_1 + \cdots + b_nx_n = h.$$

Basically if you add up a bunch of numbers and what you get is larger than their least common multiple then by removing some of those numbers you can get exactly the least common multiple.

I tried to come up with a counter example and failed, so in a fit of arrogance I've decided that this must be true, but I don't know how to prove it.  To make it a little easier I tried assuming that the $x_i$ are relatively prime so that $h = x_1\cdots x_n$.  Then I tried using inequalities to show that for some $i$ we have $a_ix_i > d$, cause then we could choose $b_i = d/x_i$ and all other $b = 0$.  But it didn't work, turns out that doesn't need to be the case.  So I'm stuck.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Do we assume $a_i,b_i$ are positive integers, or can they be positive reals?

Comment: Positive integers, or $0$.

Comment: $3$ and $4$ have least common multiple $12$. We know that $3(3) + 4(1) = 13 > 12$. How do we proceed from here?

Comment: A countexample!!  And a simple one, I can't believe I missed it.  I guess it's just not true.

Comment: Do you want to refine/delete your question, or should I post the counterexample as an answer?

Comment: You should post it and I'll accept, I don't really have a deeper motivation, so I'm not sure what I would refine it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers $3$ and $4$ have least common multiple $12$. We know that $3(3) + 4(1) = 13 > 12$. However, we cannot remove copies of $3$ or $4$ to get $12$. Thus the conjecture, as stated, is false.